# findOneAndUpdate not returning updated document in MongoDb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, database

> I have the following code to find and update a field of an embedded document in MongoDb.

```
var fieldToIncrement = { $inc: {} };
        fieldToIncrement.$inc['options_counter.'+field[0]] = 1;
        console.log(fieldToIncrement);

        db.collection('polls').findOneAndUpdate(
            {_id: user_id},
            fieldToIncrement, 
            {
                returnNewDocument: true
            }, function(err, doc){
                if(err){console.log("Error updating the document")};
                if(doc){
                    callback(doc);
                }
            }
        )
```

> My data structure looks like so

```
_id:"57e0149dcb0b20156878598d"
options:"osgn, srgounsrog, snourv"
options_counter:Object
0:0
1:0
2:0
```

> The variable field in the code is an array that contains one element which references which field of the options_counter object I want to update. However, the document is returned without any update and no error is returned either. I tried changing the

```
fieldToIncrement.$inc['options_counter.'+field[0]] = 1;
```

to

```
fieldToIncrement.$inc['opt_counter.'+field[0]] = 1;
```

> and it still doesn't return an error. This has to mean I am not
>   implementing the code correctly because opt_counter is not a field in
>   my document, therefore it SHOULD return an error.

Answer (score 0):

It won't return an error when you call it on wrong field which doesn't exist, $inc would create a field with that name with value as 0 and then increment that by 1.

After the update call if your field value is not changing (even with a wrong field) maybe you need to call the query with find({_id: user_id}) and see if it is returning the data or not, sometime we store _id as ObjectId and query it by String value and it doesn't pick the document due to type mismatch.